# Max sum of i*arr[i]

Tags: arrays, rotation

This should be a pretty straightforward logic without decreasing the space complexity but...

```
def rotate_array(a):
tempval=arr[0]
for i in range(0,n-2):
    arr[i]=arr[i+1]
arr[n-1]=tempval
return a

def max_sum(a,n):
maxval=0
for i in range(0,n-2):
    currval=0
    for j in range(0,n-1):
        currval+=j*arr[j]
    if (currval>maxval):
        maxval=currval
    rotate_array(a)
return maxval
```

This has been giving me a solution that is far from correct. Can someone please help me figure out where is the function value changing from the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `range(0,K)` generates a sequence from `0` to `(K-1)` (i.e., it does not include `K`).

This is one possible error in your code.

Comment: Ya I just changed that and it worked, thanks!!